# DATE_ADD Returning NULL on production server, working in development

Tags: mysql, sql

Development is localhost running version 5.6.16, production is 5.1.73-cll

The DATE_ADD of this query returns NULL on production, but in development is does exactly what I want it to(adds 90 minutes to the game_time column), The game_time column is a string that contains time in the following format: '21:00'.
This is the query:

```
SELECT TIME(game_time),
       DATE_ADD(TIME(game_time), 
       INTERVAL 90 MINUTE), 
       TIME(NOW()) 
  FROM games
```

What is going on? What am i doing wrong?

I know time should be in a TIMESTAMP, or TIME, but I'm working on someone elses code, I didn't start this from scratch myself.

I've also just noticed that TIME() returns different things, in development, TIME('21:00') returns 21:00:00.000000, in production I only get 21:00:00

Managed to get around, not pretty, but it works.

```
SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(game_time))+5400)
```

Answer (score 1):

You better develop with the same version as the production server:

Your old version will convert your `TIME` value to a date and because it's an invalid date, it will get NULL, see manual chapter [Conversion Between Date and Time Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-type-conversion.html)

Here's the relevant part:

> Before 5.6.4, MySQL converts a time value to a date or date-and-time
>   value by parsing the string value of the time as a date or
>   date-and-time. This is unlikely to be useful. For example, '23:12:31'
>   interpreted as a date becomes '2023-12-31'. Time values not valid as
>   dates become '0000-00-00' or NULL.

**Edit:**

To get a `TIME` value with the desired result, you could use [ADDTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime). 
This could be working:

```
SELECT TIME(game_time),
    ADDTIME (TIME(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', game_time))), 
    '01:30:00'), 
    TIME(NOW()) 
FROM games
```

untested, because I have no such old MySQL version anymore.

Comment: Ah, so I'll probably have to use STR_TO_DATE then? I managed to get what I want from STR_TO_DATE, but as soon as I put it inside the DATE_ADD function, I still get NULL.

Comment: TIME returns what I want, this works perfectly:  SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(game_time))+5400)

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the conversion to time outside the DATE_ADD:-

```
SELECT TIME(game_time), TIME(DATE_ADD(game_time, INTERVAL 90 MINUTE)), TIME(NOW()) 
FROM games
```

DATE_ADD works on a DATE or DATETIME field, and as it is you are passing it a TIME field.